# Extremely high modified memory usage and pages won't flush

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, memory, performance, sysinternals

My Lenovo Y50-70 machine suffers of extremely poor performance lately.

I'm disturbed by some memory-related issues. The machine has 8gb RAM and the *pagefile* size is currently 24gb (*"Autmomatically manage paging file size for all drives"* option is set and there's about 100gb of free space currently). I'm running *Windows 10*.

The issue is that I've noticed that there's a huge portion of memory (~60%) which is categorized as ***Modified***. A screenshot from *Sysinternals RAMMap* utility:

[image: A screenshot from SysInternals RAMMap utility]

It seems that none of the *Empty* options of the utility helps "flushing" the memory to *Modified* disk. I've tried them all, starting with *"Empty Modified Page List"* option -- there was basically no noticeable affect.

[image: RAMMap "Empty" memory options]

When using *psutil* (*Python* library), that's how the numbers sum up (*rss* and *vms*):

```
In [19]: sum([p.memory_info().rss for p in psutil.process_iter()])
Out[19]: 1973817344

In [20]: sum([p.memory_info().vms for p in psutil.process_iter()])
Out[20]: 3557965824L
```

*Windows Resource Monitor* doesn't seem to show any new insights:
[image: Windows Resource Monitor take on the issue]

As I've mentioned above -- the *pagefile* size is managed by the OS (*"Automatically"* managed) and its current size is 24gb. There's enough free space, so I don't think that there's an issue with that. Especially, when I actually use, as you can see, 2-4gb of RAM, so a 24gb pagefile seems to be more than enough.

The only thing I can think of, regarding the *pagefile*, is **fragmentation**. Is it possible that its fragmented, due to its enormous size, and that's why the system doesn't seem to be able to "flush" the *Modified* pages to disk?

That's how *Task Manager*'s *"Performance"* tab currently looks like:

[image: Task Manager performance output]

I've also downloaded and installed all the driver updates from the *Lenovo* website, suitable for my machine, except for the Bios update (I've heard of some cases where *Lenovo* machines were bricked after Bios update). A list of updated drivers: WLAN, LAN, Intel drivers (PROset wireless software, management engine interface driver, chipset driver), audio driver, energy management driver.

I'm really clueless here, and to be honest -- pretty frustrated. I'd be greatful for any piece of advice.

---

I don't know if it would be of any help, but here are some extra details regarding the machine's specs:

- Western Digital SSHD (1tb HD + 8gb SSD)
- Intel Core i7-4710HQ CPU @ 2.50 GHz
- 2x Hynix 4gb DDR3 sticks. Seems that the specific model name is *"Hynix HMT451S6AFR8A-PB 4GB PC3-12800 DDR3-1600MHz"* (found the part number using `wmich memorychip` cmd and then just searched for it online)

I'll happily provide any extra details, if needed.

---

**Edit:**
A screenshot of the *"Processes"* tab in *RAMMap*  (there's no visible leak, as far as I can tell):

[image: RAMMap "Processes" tab]

Comment: In RAMmap go to processes tab and sort on "Modified" column. Something like this is usually a memory leak.

Comment: @HoD yes, I know this tab, The numbers doesn't seem to add up to 5gb. There's no visible leak there.

Comment: That's really annoying. Do you have the latest drivers from Lenovo? I've seen this from a bad WiFi card driver. You can try adding the Handles column in the task manager, that might give a clue.

Comment: @HoD I've downloaded and installed all the driver updates from the Lenovo website, suitable for my machine, except for the BIOS update (I've heared of some cases that Lenovo machines were bricked after Bios update, so I'm kinda scared). List of updated drivers: WLAN, LAN, Intel drivers (PROset wireless software, management engine interface driver, chipset driver), audio driver, energy management driver.

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin, run **wpr.exe -start CPU -start ReferenceSet -filemode && timeout 20 && wpr.exe -stop C:\MemoryUsage.etl** now zip the ETL and share it (Onedrive share link).

Comment: have you captured the trace? it shows more details and helps me to analyze it. if you don't provide this information, we have to close the question as "too broad".